# JsonPath : how to extract multiple values and use function.?

Tags: java, json, xpath, jsonpath

XPath resolves this expression "concat(name,type)".
Can I do this in JsonPath as well.? - extracting multiple values in one go and using some function on it.

I am using google's java implementation of JsonPath.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check out DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) which extends the global object JSON with the method "search". Using this method, you can query JSON structure with XPath expressions. To see this library in action, check out the **live XPath evaluator**:

http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator